# How to use ngRoute when to execute simple Javascript

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have one Controller and no templates.

I simply want to execute a javascript function when the url is /warenkorb
(http://server.com:3000/shop.html#/warenkorb)

```
var warenkorb = angular.module('warenkorb', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])

    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/warenkorb', {
                controller: "WarenkorbCtrl",
                resolve: {
                    // I will cause a 1 second delay
                    cart_visible: function () {
                       showWarenkorb();                            
                       return true;
                    }
                }
            });
    });

var showWarenkorb = function(){
    $('#response').css('display', 'none');
    $('#modal').fadeIn();
}
var hideWarenkorb = function(){
    $('#modal').fadeOut();
}
```

How would I do this?
In my sample showWarenkorb() is never called.

Comment: Show your controller. Where are you calling the resolve `cart_visible` function? The resolve property function should always return a promise

Comment: thx. i stuck to keep it simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from time to time angularjs is just an overkill

i used which i called in a controller. works.

```
// simple routing
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```